# python division precision

Tags: python, division

I am aware of floating point being inaccurate and would like to know the best way to get  `0.08354` instead of `(0.08353999999999999)` when I do the following in Python:

```
d = 8.354/100

print (d)
```

Comment: `round(0.08353999999999999, 6) `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the builtin `round()` function:

```
>>> d = 8.354/100
>>> d
0.08353999999999999
>>> round(d, 6)
0.08354
>>>
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want absolute precision, use [Decimals](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/decimal.html):

```
>>> import decimal
>>> decimal.Decimal('8.354') / 10
Decimal('0.8354')
```

Comment: That's not working here, decimal.Decimal(2110.32)/decimal.Decimal(0.24) =
Decimal('8793.000000000001007527394847'). Any other solutions?

Comment: You’re already using floats there. Don’t. Use string literals instead, as shown in my answer.

Comment: That worked, decimal.Decimal(str(2110.32))/decimal.Decimal(str(0.24))=Decimal('8793'). Now I am wondering about the tradeoff between 3 conversions (float->str, float->str, str->int) and the accuracy required in my use case. They've gotta add some better methods for this on Python.

Comment: Why `decimal.Decimal(str(2110.32))`!? Just do `decimal.Decimal('2110.32')`!

Comment: Because 2110.32 isn't a constant. It is an input which can be any arbitrary number.

Comment: Then your case isn’t what you present here. You best write a new question with all the details.